# How to use multiple condition passing in props and running block of code

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use `if elseif else` condition in my method which I want to trigger depending on what I dropdown I select. I don't know why is it not working or if is it possible? Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-grass-0bptl?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) to demonstrate

```
<HelloWorld :msg="msg"/>Select number
<HelloWorld :msg="hi"/>


validate(val) {
  if (val === "msg") {
    alert("msg");
  } else if (val === "hi") {
    alert("hi");
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are passing a variable on the props, not string, change `:msg="msg"` to `:msg="'msg'"` or `msg="msg"`, and `:msg="hi"` to `:msg="'hi'"` or `msg="hi"`
2. on HelloWorld component, you are supposed to to check `if (this.msg === "msg")` instead of `if (val === "msg")`

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-water-dxmuz

Comment: why we put `"' '"` quote inside the quote?

Comment: Because if you dont, vue will detects it as a variable, not string.

Comment: Just remove the `:` in front of msg. `msg="hi"` is a string. No need for single quotes within double quotes

Comment: @Rie remove `:` that will break the props and `:` is binding to props

Comment: @Nofel not really, you can pass props without binding (`:`). As explained [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props), you can use `:` to bind dynamic property (like variable), if it's a static string, you dont need to bind them.

Comment: uhhh... `:msg"'hi'"` is clearly a static string without any binding whatsoever. Basically what @Owl said